# Unable to get results from simple job

Tags: azure, beagleboneblack, node-red, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to get a simple JSON data from my BeagleboneBlack to my Azure SQL Database. I have NodeRed running sending this message to the IoT Hub:

```
{   "deviceId": "device001",   
"key": "LvZdO3O/W5AnuD5zddEHZtCTDmCZwtlDeuN86LSI==",   
"protocol": "amqp",   "data": "{data1: 25, data2: 20}" }
```

Here is the documentation for why the message is formated this way: http://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-azure-iot-hub

I seem to be receiving the messages from the IoT Hub with no problems. I can am able to keep track of number of messages received but I ofc I can't see them.

So here is where stream analytics come in. I have tested both my input (the IoT hub) and the output (the SQL database).

This is the query I am running:

```
SELECT
    *
INTO
    [dbOutput]
FROM
    [theoracareBBBinput]
```

And my table is configured to receive data1 and data2 like its being sent. I can start the Job with no problem but nothing gets saved to the database. Meanwhile I know the messages are being received from the IoT Hub.

When I upload sample data, my query returns results exactly as expected.

I tried to "Sample data from Input" but every time I try I get "There was an error processing your request. Please try again in a few moments.

What am I missing here?

Comment: NodeRed **continue** sending messages to the IoT Hub **while you tried to "Sample data from Input"** ?

Comment: When you start the job, do you see any errors in operation log? In monitoring page, do you see any input events being read? Those two are first steps to debug such cases.

Comment: As Vignesh suggested you should check for any errors, but this "And my table is configured to receive data1 and data2 like its being sent." from your question hints that you may need to un-nest data1 and data2 from field data, which is a record. Something like this: `SELECT i.data.data1, i.data.data2, i.* INTO [dbOutput] FROM [theoracareBBBinput] as i`.
If you just `SELECT *...` the output schema will not contain fields named data1 and data2.